# How to solve 404 errors with iframe tag

Tags: iframe, seo, nofollow

Recently I'm getting 404 error on webmasterstools in google.

This is my website http://www.farsnews.in. I use iframe tag to show the content of a web page in my contents.

I've used the iframe tag by rel=nofollow but i think Google doesnt pay attention on rel ellement of an iframe tag.

how can i tell Google to not follow the src element of an iframe tag?

I can't use the meta tag no-index or even no-follow, as the content that is showing on my website it not officially on my website, so because of this we cant use meta tags.

Answer (score 0):

use a blank page with iFrame for Show Your Page Content and use  on head of this page
And Call this Page in a ifram on mainpage

sourcepage ---> blank page with ifram ---> show on your site with ifram